# Windows.open() JavaScript not working in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I am trying to open new window using below code. Its working properly in google chrome and firefox but in IE its doing merging of windows.
If i logged in through user1 then one new window gets open but when i login with user2 then instead of opening new window it replaces user session of user1 with user2.

Here's my code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "name", "var myWindow =  window.open('" & pageurl & "','name','titlebar=yes,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,status=yes,overflow=hidden;menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,left=0,top=0,width=(screen.availWidth),height= (screen.availHeight)');   myWindow.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight); ; myWindow.focus(); ", True)
```

I want to open new window in IE everytime when new user logged in to system.

Comment: So the problem is that your popup is being reused?

Comment: @kblok.. yes... I want new popup window everytime.

Comment: Check out my answer, tell me if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be your `pageurl` variable is incorrect or contains spaces. (By the way, it's not clear where you got it from, so you might want to change it to `window.location.href`).

Also, try using `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` instead:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "name", "(js code)", true);
```

When you use `RegisterStartupScript`, it will render your script **after** all the elements in the page (right before the form's end tag). This enables the script to call or reference page elements without the possibility of it not finding them in the Page's DOM.

On the other hand, when you use `RegisterClientScriptBlock`, the script is rendered right after the `Viewstate` tag, but **before** any of the page elements.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in `window.open` is the window name/id. if you leave the same name, As you are naming that window `'name'`, the window is going to be reused. I recommend you to use `_blank`:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "name", "var myWindow =  window.open('" & pageurl & "','_blank','titlebar=yes,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,status=yes,overflow=hidden;menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,left=0,top=0,width=(screen.availWidth),height= (screen.availHeight)');   myWindow.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight); ; myWindow.focus(); ", True)
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp